# Multiple errors when writing image file with OpenOCD and Stlink v2 to NRF51822

Tags: swd, openocd

I want to flash a firmware on my nrf51822 module I was trying an example from Nordic, I concatenated the bin file with the s110 file and it worked fine. Now, when I went ahead to flash the bin file, here's what I got (I followed the wiki http://github.com/RIOT-OS/RIOT/wiki/Board:-yunjia-nrf51822)

```
> flash probe 0
nRF51822-QFAA(build code: Gx0) 256kB Flash
flash 'nrf51' found at 0x00000000

> flash banks
#0 : nrf51.flash (nrf51) at 0x00000000, size 0x00040000, buswidth 1, chipwidth 1
#1 : nrf51.uicr (nrf51) at 0x10001000, size 0x00000000, buswidth 1, chipwidth 1
```

for some reason,  I have no idea why `size 0x00000000`.. any clue?

If I do

```
> nrf51 mass_erase
> flash banks
#0 : nrf51.flash (nrf51) at 0x00000000, size 0x00040000, buswidth 1, chipwidth 1
#1 : nrf51.uicr (nrf51) at 0x10001000, size 0x00000100, buswidth 1, chipwidth 1
```

Now when I try to flash the firmware, I get the following:

```
> flash write_image erase    ~/NRF51822/Board/pca10001/s110/ble_app_proximity/gcc/_build/test.bin 0
auto erase enabled
Padding image section 0 with 12596 bytes
using fast async flash loader. This is currently supported
only with ST-Link and CMSIS-DAP. If you have issues, add
"set WORKAREASIZE 0" before sourcing nrf51.cfg to disable it
jtag status contains invalid mode value - communication failure
error waiting for target flash write algorithm
Failed to enable read-only operation
Failed to write to nrf51 flash
error writing to flash at address 0x00000000 at offset 0x00000000

Previous state query failed, trying to reconnect
```

It's driving me crazy, I have no clue why that's happening. I couldn't get it to work.

Note: I have an STLink-v2 dongle, no STM32 board involved. I also updated the stlink-v2 firmware using stlink utility.

One last thing, the test.bin file I'm using is basically the output of the following (using S110 v6 and example from sdk v6):
`srec_cat ~/Downloads/s110_nrf51822_6.2.1/s110_nrf51822_6.2.1_softdevice.hex  -intel ble_app_proximity_s110_xxaa.hex -intel -o ./test.bin --line-length=44`

Answer (score 1):

After `nrf51 mass_erase`, you probably need a `reset halt`.

If that doesn't help:

```
If you have issues, add
"set WORKAREASIZE 0" before sourcing nrf51.cfg to disable it
```

Did you try that?  That should eliminate problems, but the flashing will be slow.  You may have better luck with a value greater than 0 but smaller than the default, like "set WORKAREASIZE 0x2000".